# gettext - Cant get the Lithuanian language code to work

Tags: php, gettext

I have implimented [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) with my site and am providing 15 different translations which all work but one

**Lithuania** - I can't seem to figure out the language/country code to make it work.

```
putenv("LC_ALL=lt_LT");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "lt_LT");
bindtextdomain("messages", "/home/path/to/locale");
textdomain("messages");
bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", 'UTF-8');
```

I first check my `locale -a` on my box and I have the following enabled

```
lt_LT
lt_LT.iso885913
lt_LT.utf8
```

I have tried all three and they do not work.

Any ideas of any other codes I can try?

Comment: Can you change the `LC_ALL` to `LANG` in `putenv`? Apart from that, make sure you set the other options correctly (text domain, directory, etc.). Then you could try the `lt_LT.utf8` variant instead. And finally, `LC_MESSAGES` *could* be enough if you’re only interested in translating strings.

Comment: I added the rest of my code and Yes I did already try `LANG` instead of `LC_ALL`. I also tried `lt_LT.utf8` as well.

Comment: Looks good, at least if the improvements are applied. Try wrapping every single one of these calls inside `var_dump` to see the return values and check them against the expected return values as found in the PHP documentation. Some call must be failing. Also keep in mind that you have to make these calls at the top of every request where you want to use your translated strings.

Comment: I just figured it out, for some reason `gettext` didn't like the keywords Facebook and Google and when trying to process the `.mo` version would encase the words in double quotes which would break it and never create the .mo file. Since I use an automated script I built to rebuild my `.mo` files I didn't notice the error till I went into terminal and ran it manually...man I love `gettext`!